# Subgraph of a complement of a cycle $C_4$

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Can someone help with this:
We have a cycle $C_4$. The complement of $C_4$ is a graph $2K_2$.

I have to find an induced subgraph of a complement of $C_4$.
Then, I have to find the chromatic number of a induced subgraph of $2K_2$ and the clique number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$4$ being a pretty small number, you can solve this problem by drawing your graph. $C_4$ is essentially the "square graph". The complement is the 2 diagonals. If you want a (strict) induced subgraph, then just take of the two diagonals. The chromatic number will be 2, with the opposite corners having different colors. Finally, the clique number is $2$, as you can cover the complement with 2 cliques : the diagonals themselves.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was thinking in this way and I obtained a such solution.